# What is the reason for this error message? Error: nothing to repeat at position 0

Tags: python, error-handling

I am running below code for replacing '+' with '' in Anaconda Python

```py
app_data['Installs']=app_data['Installs'].str.replace(',','',regex=True)
app_data['Installs']=app_data['Installs'].str.replace('+','',regex=True)
```

The first line of replacing comma worked but the second statement shows error:

```
error: nothing to repeat at position 0
```

Could you please explain on the reason for the error message?

Comment: Why are you setting `regex=True`? `+` has a special meaning in regular expressions and you're not using its proper syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You have the parameter regex set true. It means that the first argument you pass must be a regex expression. In regex + is a keyword meaning something preceding should repeat 1 or more times. I suppose you want to eliminate the + sign, for this either use + in your code or change regex to False.